# UIWebview inside UICollectionView, how to stop reloading webview on scrolling collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiwebview, uicollectionviewcell

I have UIWebView inside UICollectionViewCell, whenever i scroll collection view my webview getting reloaded. It is taking so much time.

I kept some booleans to stop reloading webview, if that cell's webview is already loaded. But this causing cells mismatch issue (last loaded or other cell webview data is showing in cells)

I am loading webview using html string.

```
cell.webView.loadHTMLString(updatedString, baseURL: nil)
```

My UI looks like...[image]

Comment: You could put the webview inside of a `.xib` file and add it to the cell. In cellForRow when you add the view to collectionviewcell cache the view in a the ViewController. 

`var cache = [IndexPath: UIView]`

So in cellForRow you attempt to grab a cached view, and if it doesn't exist, instantiate one and add it to the cache.

Comment: This causing cells misplace issue. Other cells content is displaying in wrong cells

Comment: Have you considered loading the web data into an array, then use the array to load the collection view?

Comment: are you using cell reusing or you store each cell in memory?